# how to save tensorflow model to pickle file

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pickle

I want to save a Tensorflow model and then later use it for deployment purposes. I dont want to use `model.save()` to save it because my purpose is to somehow 'pickle' it and use it in a different system where tensorflow is not installed, like:

```
model = pickle.load(open(path, 'rb'))
model.predict(prediction_array)
```

Earlier with sklearn, when i was pickling a KNN model, it was successful and i was able to run inference without installing sklearn.

But when I tried to pickle my Tensorflow model, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:/VA_nlu_addition_branch_lite/nlu_stable2/train.py", line 21, in <module>
pickle.dump(model, open('saved/model.p', 'wb'))
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

My model looks like this:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
            keras.Input(shape=(len(x[0]))),
            keras.layers.Dense(units=16, activation='elu'),
            keras.layers.Dense(units=8, activation='elu'),
            keras.layers.Dense(units=len(y[0]), activation='softmax'),
        ])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x, y, epochs=200, batch_size=8)
pickle.dump(model, open('saved/model.p', 'wb'))
```

**Model summary**

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 16)                1680
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 8)                 136
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 20)                180
=================================================================
Total params: 1,996
Trainable params: 1,996
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Here is a [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514440/serve-tensorflow-model-without-installing-tensorflow) regarding this problem, but the link in the answer was expired.

Also here is [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56260192/load-tensorflow-model-without-importing-tensorflow), but i didn't quite get it.

I have a very simple model, no checkpoints, nothing much complicated, so is there some way to save the Tensorflow model object to a binary file? Or even if its multiple binary files, i dont mind, but it just doesn't need to use tensoflow, if the [numpy solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56260192/load-tensorflow-model-without-importing-tensorflow) would help, i would use that, but i dont know how to implement it here. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: You need to extract weights from the model, create an array out of them and pickle that array. I'm not sure how else it can be done otherwise.

Answer (score 7):

Using `joblib` seems to work on `TF` 2.8 and since you have a very simple model, you can train it on Google Colab and then just use the pickled file on your other system:

```
import joblib
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(5,)),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=16, activation='elu'),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=8, activation='elu'),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=5, activation='softmax'),
        ])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
x = tf.random.normal((20, 5))
y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(tf.random.uniform((20, 1), maxval=5, dtype=tf.int32))
model.fit(x, y, epochs=200, batch_size=8)
joblib.dump(model, 'model.pkl')
```

Load model without `tf`:

```
import joblib
import numpy as np
print(joblib.__version__)

model = joblib.load("/content/model.pkl")
print(model(np.random.random((1,5))))
```

```
1.1.0
tf.Tensor([[0.38729233 0.04049021 0.06067584 0.07901421 0.43252742]], shape=(1, 5), dtype=float32)
```

But it is hard to tell if it is really that "straight-forward" without knowing your system specs.

Comment: hey, its not working, i was using tf 2.0, now it shows `TypeError: can't pickle _thread._local objects`. So does that means its wrong with tensorflow versions? For my specs, i have an intel i5 x64 bit processor, and using tensorflow cpu version 2.0.0

Comment: Yeah, I think, starting from version 2.6.0, keras models can be pickled..A tf version upgrade should solve the problem..but maybe try what I suggested: train your model on google colab and just load the binary on your system

Comment: so when i loaded it locally, it says `Using TensorFlow backend.` (although i haven't imported tensorflow in my script... and it throws an exception: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.saving'`. The exception is coming from: `File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\pickle.py", line 1388, in find_class
    __import__(module, level=0)`, so this error still belongs to pickle right? or should i have to upgrade my python as well to that of Colab's version?

Comment: Which method are you experimenting with right now?

Comment: training on colab and then loading the binary locally for inference

Comment: Are you using joblib or pickle?

Comment: i am using joblib

Comment: Yes so the difference in my joblib and python versions to that of Colab was causing the mess. Both the system's joblib and python versions should be same. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For `TensorFlow` models created using `keras`, please save models in `.h5` extension as explained in a similar answer here:

[Error , Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for ram to unpickle a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71676507/error-unsuccessful-tensorslicereader-constructor-failed-to-find-any-matching):

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model as tfk__load_model
# ...
# fit model:
# model.fit(x, y, ...)

# save fitted model to file
model.save('model.h5')

# load fitted model
fitted_model = tfk__load_model('model.h5')
```