# Error , Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for ram to unpickle a file

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, pickle, joblib

I am running into this error , i can't unpickle a file on my jupyter notebook:

```
import os 
import pickle
import joblib
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
filename = open("loan_model3.pkl", "rb")
mdl = pickle.load(filename)
mdl.close()
```

and it always shows the below error message , even tho i'vce upgraded all my libraries

Error Message:

> FileNotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for ram://89506590-ec42-44a9-b67c-3ee4cc8e884e/variables/variables  You may be trying to load on a different device from the computational device. Consider setting the `experimental_io_device`option in`tf.saved_model.LoadOptions` to the io_device such as '/job:localhost'.

I tried to upgrade my libraries but still didn't work.

Comment: Hi @abdalla Adding `./` in front of the file name like this `filename = open("./loan_model3.pkl", "rb")` should help. Let us know if the error still persists. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Tfer3 , i've tried that but  unfortunately the error still there .

Comment: Is the pickle file and the notebook in the same folder?

Comment: Hi @Tfer3 sorry for late reply , yes they are both in the same folder , im using jupyter notebook , so they are in the same folder i saved my .py file

Comment: Could you please share the steps used to save the model? Thanks!

Comment: Hey, were you able to solve this problem ?? I am facing the same issue currently.

Comment: Any solution? Currently facing same

Comment: Same issue here as well ... please advise

Comment: Any solution for this issue? Currently encountering the same

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error too when I was trying to store my **Sequential** model in .pkl file, since **Sequential** model is a TensorFlow Keras model so we have to store it in .h5 file and Keras saves models in this format as it can easily store the weights and model configuration in a single file.

**Code:**

```
   from keras.models import load_model
   model.save('model.h5')
   model_final = load_model('model.h5')
```

Answer (score 0):

Idk if you are still here but I found the solution. basically you should not save the tensorflow model into a pickle file but instead into h5 file

```
## save model
save_path = './model.h5'
model.save(save_path)
## load tensorflow model
model = keras.models.load_model(save_path)
```

This worked for me. Hope this helps you too.

Comment: Hi Abdul Munim , Thank you for your response , i will try this and revert back to you.

Comment: My apologies for the late reply , iw ill give it a try , so sorry fro replying late had some problems here.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
import tensorflow as tf
path = './model.h5'
model.save(path )
loaded_model= tf.keras.models.load_model(path )
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue, but by saving the model as .h5 file worked for me. Now i'm able to load .h5 model.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is a duplicate answer. A similar answer already exists.