# FileNotFound when trying to pickle TensorFlow object in GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pickle, dill

I'm running the code below, and it works perfectly if TensorFlow is installed *without* GPU. But if installed *with* GPU, I get a FileNotFound error when I try to load the object.

I tried also with joblib and pickle directly, and I always get the same error.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import dill

def Generator():

    z_dim = 60

    FEATURES_LIST = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc" ]
    ME_FEATURES_LIST = ["ddd", "eee", "fff" ]

    NUM_FEATURES = len(FEATURES_LIST)
    NUM_ME_FEATURES = len(ME_FEATURES_LIST)

    z = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(z_dim,), dtype='float32')
    y = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(NUM_ME_FEATURES,), dtype='float32')
    tr = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype='bool')
  
    x = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([z, y])
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(z_dim * NUM_ME_FEATURES, activation="relu")(x)
    out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(NUM_FEATURES, activation='sigmoid')(x)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[z, y, tr], outputs=(out, y))

    return model

G = Generator()

with open("dill_functional", 'wb') as file:
  dill.dump(G, file)

with open("dill_functional", 'rb') as file:
  G = dill.load(file)  # <--- error here

print(str(G))
```

> C:\Users\igor-.cloned\gan> python .\dill_test.py 2023-02-09
> 22:42:28.379108: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193]
> This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network
> Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in
> performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2 To enable them in other
> operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
>
> 2023-02-09 22:42:29.759547: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1616] Created device
> /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 9426 MB memory:  ->
> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0,
> compute capability: 8.6
>
> WARNING:tensorflow:Compiled the loaded model,
> but the compiled metrics have yet to be built. `model.compile_metrics`
> will be empty until you train or evaluate the model.
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "C:\Users\igor-\.cloned\gan\dill_test.py", line 32, in <module>
>   G = dill.load(file)   
>  File "C:\Users\igor-\anaconda3\envs\ai\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py", line 272, in load
>   return Unpickler(file, ignore=ignore, **kwds).load()   
>  File "C:\Users\igor-\anaconda3\envs\ai\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py", line 419, in load
>   obj = StockUnpickler.load(self)   
>  File "C:\Users\igor-\anaconda3\envs\ai\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\pickle_utils.py", line 47, in deserialize_model_from_bytecode
>   model = save_module.load_model(temp_dir)   
>  File "C:\Users\igor-\anaconda3\envs\ai\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
>   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None   
>  File "C:\Users\igor-\anaconda3\envs\ai\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py", line 933, in load_partial
>   raise FileNotFoundError(
> FileNotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for  ram://fc47ea82-4f6b-4736-9394-980cc1f14358/variables/variables
> ```
>
> You
> may be trying to load on a different device from the computational
> device. Consider setting the `experimental_io_device` option in
> `tf.saved_model.LoadOptions` to the io_device such as
> '/job:localhost'.

Comment: The traceback is messed up, could you post it with code formatting?

Comment: What's `ram://fc47ea82-4f6b-4736-9394-980cc1f14358/variables/variables`?

Comment: @tripleee I'm not sure what's `ram...` , I suspect it is the path to a memory address in my GPU's RAM where drill saved the file? I don't know why it's using RAM if I save the file to disk

Comment: Other people on stackoverflow had the same issue, looks like they resolved it using the Tensorflow keras.model to save into a hd5 format instead of using pickle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71676507/error-unsuccessful-tensorslicereader-constructor-failed-to-find-any-matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the error; I have a colabNB running here.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lZRJTVjQCzTThU_9iYNSZVwgWzVWKzuM?usp=sharing

The error seems to be with how and where your operating system is saving the model file, and is unable to locate it with *dill* . I suggest either not using it or fixing PATH for the module. Alternatively
D.Holmes's answer is working and is also present in the colab notebook.

If you are curious here is the output you **should** get (ideally) if your code is executed within a well-configured environment. (PATH issues fixed!)

The model is located here. /content/saved_model

```
Keras weights file (<HDF5 file "variables.h5" (mode r+)>) saving:
...layers
......concatenate
.........vars
......dense
.........vars
............0
............1
......dense_1
.........vars
............0
............1
......input_layer
.........vars
......input_layer_1
.........vars
......input_layer_2
.........vars
...vars
Keras model archive saving:
File Name                                             Modified             Size
variables.h5                                   2023-02-18 02:50:04        64712
config.json                                    2023-02-18 02:50:04         2083
metadata.json                                  2023-02-18 02:50:04           64
Keras model archive loading:
File Name                                             Modified             Size
variables.h5                                   2023-02-18 02:50:04        64712
config.json                                    2023-02-18 02:50:04         2083
metadata.json                                  2023-02-18 02:50:04           64
Keras weights file (<HDF5 file "variables.h5" (mode r)>) loading:
...layers
......concatenate
.........vars
......dense
.........vars
............0
............1
......dense_1
.........vars
............0
............1
......input_layer
.........vars
......input_layer_1
.........vars
......input_layer_2
.........vars
...vars
<keras.engine.functional.Functional object at 0x7f752cd6b820>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can store the model's weight by:

```
model_weight = model.get_weights()
// Store by pickle
pickle.dump(model_weight, open('model_weight.pkl', 'wb'))

// Load by pickle
weight = pickle.load(open('model_weight.pkl', 'rb'))
model.set_weights(weight)
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, you can try setting the experimental_io_device argument to the tf.saved_model.load() function to specify the device where the checkpoint files are located. For example, if the files are located on the CPU, you can try the below one

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
G = tf.saved_model.load("path/to/saved/model", 
options=tf.saved_model.LoadOptions(experimental_io_device='/job:localhost'))
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why but entering the exact location of this file fixes it.
If you are using windows don't use " " or ";" in the path.

works:

```
with open("C:/model/dill_functional", 'rb') as file:
  G = dill.load(file)
```

not works:

```
with open("C:/users/some; path/model/dill_functional", 'rb') as file:
  G = dill.load(file)
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried with the full path and I get the same error. Did you make it fail first with GPU?

Comment: yeah can you try to save model more simple path like "C:/model/dill_functional"

Comment: We tried that and many other ways and always get the same error